# How to get HTML of DOM element in Capybara?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, inspect

I want to debug/develop code using irb:

```
irb> require "capybara"
irb> include Capybara::DSL
irb> Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
irb> visit "http://example.com"
```

But how do I get an HTML of the element I found?

```
irb> s = find(".user-pane")
=> #<Capybara::Element tag="nav">
irb> s.native.inner_html
NoMethodError: undefined method `inner_html' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x007fc1da191b28>
```

> gem list

```
capybara (2.4.4)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
selenium-webdriver (2.43.0)
```

Comment: could you provide a generic domain that can be visited and has `.user-pane`? Have you tried `find('user-pane`)?

Comment: @Bala, reproducible for google.com and find("#hplogo")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solutions, that I've found on SO and elsewhere don't work:

- Why `.inner_html` doesn't work anymore?
  Because `.native` is now WebDriver, not Nokogiri object.
- Why `.native.get_attribute` doesn't work?
  Because the method has the name different from Python.

So the answer is: `s.native.attribute('outerHTML')`
But it takes near 5 second to accomplish even on google.com page.

Comment: Aha, you got it.+1 for sharing

Comment: FYI this does not work for Capybara and Poltergeist. page.find(...).native returns Capybara::Poltergeist::Node, which doesn't have an 'attribute' method

Comment: For Capybara w/Poltergeist, you can use `s['outerHTML']` and that will work. For example: `find('#some_button')['outerHTML']`

Answer (score 1):

My Capybara `find('#name').native` returns type `Nokogiri::XML::Element`, which has a `to_html` method (among others). If that's what `native` returns for you, then `s.native.to_html` should give you the HTML.